# Detect when touches stop

Tags: android, touch

I am making a game in which if the user lifts up their finger, they will lose, but I don't know how to check that. If touches are stopped, I want `boolean start` to be set to false. Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use OnTouchListener. you just modify below code as per your requirement

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  int eventaction = event.getAction();

                    switch (eventaction) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "The button has been pressed " ,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       // finger touches the button
                            break;

                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "The button has been release",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // finger leaves the button
                            break;
                    }

                return false;
            }
        });
```